# Creating, Editing, and Retrieving a List

Tags: android

I have a class that collects a series of strings (contact's names) and I need a way to save them all to a List.  I have searched everywhere but everything I find has to do with ListViews.  I need a method that will allow me to add, edit, and delete my strings from an .xml file.  I have tried to use  located in resources/values but it does not seem that you can edit the file within a class.  The reason I need this is so that the user can load specific lists on command by their name, so using a simple String array will not suffice.  When the user selects a specific list file, the string values within it would be placed in a string array and displayed in a ListView.  What methods would I use to achieve this (besides SQlite)?

I appreciate any and all advice

-Nate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What methods would I use to achieve this (besides SQlite)?

An XML file. Or a JSON file. Or a CSV file. Or a plain text file with one string per line. Or any number of other file-based storage strategies. Use standard Java file I/O coupled with whatever parsing/encoding (XML, JSON, CSV, etc.) approach you want. Store the file in the directory retrieved from `getFilesDir()` in your activity.